# Dual monitor touchscreen calibration

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I have an Acer X23H monitor and HP 2209t touchscreen monitor and Geforce 7100/nforce 630i card

Whenever I touch the HP screen, it is the Acer that is affected. It does not matter if the HP is the primary monitor or not.

On its own the HP functions as it should, but once I connect the Acer, the HP touchscreen loses functionality and is somehow "transferred" to the Acer.

Am stumped. I believe the solution lies in calibrating the HP, but am not able to find where to do this.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01951805.pdf) on the HP website, there are touch applications on the CD that comes with the monitor. If it is anything like the ones we use at work (different make) then you should be able to setup a multi-monitor arrangement using one of the applications.

From the manual:

> Control of the Touch Function Note:
>
> 1. Before using the touch function, make
>      sure the USB cable is connected, the
>      touch applications from the CD-ROM are
>      installed if you are running Windows
>      XP and the Window's operating system
>      is started.

I believe the reference to XP only concerns the USB drivers.